# django app: Cannot assign "''": "ImageText.link" must be a "Link" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms, django-1.5

I'm building an app for my Django 1.5.1 and Django-cms installation.
The app meant to permit to upload an image linked to an URL.
My code :

**cms_plugins.py**

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.plugins.text.widgets.wymeditor_widget import WYMEditor
from django.forms.fields import CharField
from models import ImageText

class ImageTextPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ImageText
    name = "video wall"
    render_template = "video.html"

def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    context.update({
        'object':instance,
    })
    return context


  plugin_pool.register_plugin(ImageTextPlugin)
```

**models.py**

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.db.models import fields 
 from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField
 from filer.fields.file import FilerFileField
 from cms.models import CMSPlugin


 class ImageText(CMSPlugin):
      image = FilerImageField(related_name="image0")
      link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from models import ImageText

 class ImageTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


  admin.site.register(ImageText, ImageTextAdmin)
```

**video.html**

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" rel="group" href="{{ instance.link }}">
   <div class="video">
        <img alt="work module image" src="{{ instance.image }}" />
        </div>
 </a>
```

When I try to install an instance of my app in a cms placeholder I have this error:

```
 ValueError at /admin/cms/page/51/edit-plugin/1839/
 Cannot assign "''": "ImageText.link" must be a "Link" instance.
```

I don't understand what causing that. Any idea?

**my pip freeze**

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
Django==1.5.1
MySQL-python==1.2.4
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.2.1
South==0.8.2
cmsplugin-filer==0.9.5
cmsplugin-zinnia==0.4
django-appconf==0.6
django-blog-zinnia==0.12.3
django-classy-tags==0.4
django-cms==2.4.2
django-filer==0.9.5
django-haystack==1.2.7
django-mptt==0.5.2 
django-polymorphic==0.5.3
django-sekizai==0.7
django-tagging==0.3.1
django-tinymce==1.5.1
django-twitter-tag==1.2
django-xmlrpc==0.1.5
easy-thumbnails==1.4
html5lib==1.0b3
pyparsing==1.5.7
pysolr==3.1.0
pytz==2013.7
requests==2.0.1
six==1.2.0
twitter==1.9.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: Add the constraint `null=True` and try again.

Comment: I have try and it gave me Cannot assign None: "ImageText.link" does not allow null values.

Comment: Oh.. You need a migration to allow null values in the database. either use south, or if it is in trivial stages of the application, just add drop the database, and syncdb again

Comment: yep I think I need to drop the table....let me try..

Comment: dropped the table and syncdb ..but din't work :( - same error

Comment: Intersting !! can you inspect the database column ? Is it nullable ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here has not much to do with your schema specifically but with how django handles `OneToOne` relationships.

When you subclass `CMSPlugin`, django creates an implicit `OneToOne` relationship from your model to the `CMSPlugin` and vice versa.

This being the case, imagine the following scenario:

I have a plugin called `Title`:

```
class Title(CMSPlugin):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

the model above would have access to the `CMSPlugin` table via a `cmsplugin_ptr` attribute and a `CMSPlugin` instance would have access to it's `Title` via the automatically created attribute "title" <-- classname.lower()

So given the example above, if now I want another plugin called `Video`

```
class VideoPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

here's the problem, when you save the video plugin, the `title` field clashes with the automatically generated title attribute from the previous plugin thus throwing a 
`Cannot assign "''": "VideoPlugin.title" must be a "Title" instance`.

This is mentioned very lightly in the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.3/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#storing-configuration).

So all you have to do in your case is rename the `link` field to something else.
I usually name the fields of my plugins with their classname, so in your case I would end up with

```
class ImageText(CMSPlugin):
      image_text_image = FilerImageField(related_name="image0")
      image_text_link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

this way you are sure to avoid any clashes with other plugins.

Comment: Yep - that was it !! Thanks a lot - didn't realise it was working like that :)

Comment: This is accurate in a technical sense and might be the only way out when things have already gotten sticky.

The cleaner approach would be to agree on a naming convention of the plugin classes themselves.

If every plugin author would agree on adding the `Plugin` suffix to the plugin model, this would not be a problem.

I've opened an Issue for this at django-cms: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/3204